# Cannot Bind JSON response to textbox using jquery ajax (MVC 4)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I cannot bind the json values to text-box. i have searched internet but couldn't find any solution for this. I'm sharing my code

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#Email').mousemove(function () {
        var errormsg = "";
        var amount = $('#Email').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/Admin/Ticket/GetInfo',
            data: { term: amount },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#error').html(data)
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                $('#error').html("Primitive Functions not allowed.")
            }
        });
    });
})
```

**My Action Method:**

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetInfo(string term)
        {

            var result = (from r in db.Customers
                          where r.Email.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())
                          select new { r.Email, r.UserName }).Distinct().Take(5);
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="Email" />
<input type="text" id= "Company" />
```

Comment: so its still unresolved..:)

Comment: @EhsanSajjad yes but now only one error

Comment: @EhsanSajjad it is not binding the value to textbox

Comment: can you show the json returned???

Comment: @EhsanSajjad this is the json response [{"Email":"hjskd@de.com","UserName":"635363413214220532"}]

Comment: @UsamaSheikh: you need to specify a proper key name, instead of this `data: { term: amount },`  change  it to this way `data: { 'term': amount },`. because `term` is not a variable

Comment: @dreamweiver data is passed correct json is returning but OP
 is unable to bind to textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is returned as an array.

you can do like this to set value in textbox now:

```
$("#TextBoxID").val(data[0].Email);
```

Same Way you can access the second property:

```
$("#TextBoxID").val(data[0].UserName);
```

Just made a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7QZr/1/) as well.

Comment: perfect, now its solved can u please tell me where was the error?

Comment: you are seeting html in an element whose id is error ``$('#error').html(data)``

Comment: ``text()`` sets the text between the opening and closing tags of elements but for input controls we need to use ``val()`` for setting the value

Comment: can i trigger this event on mousemove and keyup event? together?

Comment: Thereotically, you can. Just put those code inside a separate function, then call it in your `mouseover` and `keyup` event

Comment: @DoanCuong can u please tell me what is 0 in [0]?

Comment: As @EhsanSajjad said, Json returned an array. So in your case, `data` is an array with 1 element, and to access that element, your have to use `data[0]` - 0 is array index

Comment: in your yesterday post i think you posted incomplete json

Comment: @DoanCuong and what if i want to access the other values in JSON return?

Comment: `[{"Email":"hjskd@de.com","UserName":"635363413214220532"}]` as you can see in this json which is provided by you. `[]` indicate that this is an array. `{}` indicate an object. To access an object inside an array, you have to provide its 0-based index.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad i have this JSON result {"PartNumber":"ASD345UI32414","Manufacturer":"asdasdasd","DateCode":"asdasdasdasd","Price":120.00,"PackageCase":"asdasdasas"}

Comment: @EhsanSajjad i want to access all those and bind the values to particular textboxes

Comment: In this json, you don't need provide array index. Just use `data.PartNumber`, `data.Manufacturer`, `data.DateCode`, `data.Price` and `data.PackageCase` to retrieve value of particular variable

Comment: @DoanCuong if i don't use index then it doesn't provide any result that was the problem

Comment: it won't work youhave to ``data[0].PartNumber``  ``data[0].Manufacturer`` like this access others as well